# The main activity is not declared in AdroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, android-launcher

Every time I try to launch my app, it gives me the following error.

I've already tried to specify the activity in launch options, disable Instant Run, and change the Main Launcher activity in manifest (and also launch options), set to Default Activity, but nothing works.

It all started when I added the 'Products Page' activities in the Manifest, and this implementations to com.android.feature and com.android.application:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'



     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="true">

            <activity android:name=".home.Home"
                android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:label="@string/app_name">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>


            <activity android:name=".navigation.ActivityOne"
                android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter android:order="1">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data
                        android:host="coffeehour.app.com.br"
                        android:pathPattern="/.*"
                        android:scheme="https" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".navigation.ActivityTwo"
                android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
                <intent-filter android:order="1">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data
                        android:host="coffeehour.app.com.br"
                        android:pathPattern="/.*"
                        android:scheme="https" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".navigation.ActivityThree"
                android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                android:noHistory="true">
                <intent-filter android:order="1">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data
                        android:host="coffeehour.app.com.br"
                        android:pathPattern="/.*"
                        android:scheme="https" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

 <!-- Products Page -->
        <activity
            android:name=".products.OpenScreen">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".products.NewUser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".products.MainAppPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_app_page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".products.IndividualProduct"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_individual_product"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".products.ShoppingCartWindow" />
        <activity android:name=".products.CheckOutScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".products.ForgotPassword" />
        <activity android:name=".products.IndividualProductSeller" />
        <activity android:name=".products.AddProductForm"></activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you change the MainActivity on your android studio Manifest it compiles from caches so the first solution to your problem is Goto - File-Invalidate Caches and Restart will solve your problem.

Comment: @ Livia Castilholi Santiago Okay please see package names are matching or not and see carefully misspelled activities on you activity and finally if you can please put screen shot of your manifest file and mainactivity packages.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to post the code than the screenshots:

I've already sent the manifest code, and here is the MainActivity package names:

```
 package br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.home;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.R;
import br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.navigation.ActivityOne;
import br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.navigation.ActivityThree;
import br.com.app.coffeehour.coffee_hour.navigation.ActivityTwo;
```